# How to enable revenue in firebase analytics?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-analytics

I already sent my purchase data in firebase analytics. Now I want the revenue graph of firebase analytics. How can I generate that?

[see image from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj7My.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The revenue in Firebase overview is the sum of revenue from purchases, in-app purchases, subscriptions, and advertising revenue for the last 7 days of your apps. Could you confirm you're getting this events?